# Partition missing in zpool import and blkid, but visible in gdisk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, zfs

After a crash of my root btrfs I needed to force a shutdown with the power button. After re-installation of a root filesystem (independent from the ZFS pool I want to import) I no longer can import my pool `data` because the device `/dev/sdb7` is missing in `zpool import` and `sudo blkid`. It is listed in `gdisk` and files exist in `/dev/` and `/dev/disk-by-it` (however not in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`).

The output of `sudo zpool import` is

```
   pool: data
     id: 4016535649222625743
  state: FAULTED
 status: The pool metadata is corrupted.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-72
 config:

    data         FAULTED  corrupted data
    logs
      sda1       ONLINE
```

`sdb7` is the only missing device. At creation I used `/dev/disk/by-id/` referenced, but they were replaced by the resolved links to `/dev/`.

Given the output of `zpool import` and the missing device in `blkid` I see no reason to believe that there's another cause for the data corruption.

Passing `-f`, `-F` or both to `sudo zpool import` doesn't help.

I'd appreciate if solutions avoid the use of `gparted`.

I'm using SPL 0.7.0-22_gc9821f1 and ZFS 0.7.0-225_g823d48bfb installed from source on Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to add `-d /dev` to `zpool import` in order to be able to import the pool successfully. The partition still doesn't show in `blkid`, but maybe it never did and it not showing is unrelated to the issue.